# Ruby and Qt4: no `rbuic`

Tags: ruby, qt4

when I used to use Qt3, I was only have to design my program interface, then use the "rbuic" command to convert the .ui file into a .rb file, and problem solved ...
but the thing is, now I'm using Qt4, and there is no such thing like "rbuic", so I'm i suppose to write the whole ruby program to run an interface by my self, if yes, then I'll use the Qt3, at least it less painful.

Answer (score 4):

If the naming scheme is coherent with the pyqt bindings, you are probably looking for **rbuic4** ...

So it's probably something like this:

```
rbuic4 -xo main_gui.rb main_gui.ui
```